# How to insert an element in a array of ReactJS component objects (between existing elements)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of `<FilterGroup /`> objects. I want to insert a `<Conjunction />`object after each `<FilterGroup>` object except the last one.

So the array should go from:

```
[
    <FilterGroup />
    <FilterGroup />
    <FilterGroup />
    <FilterGroup />
]
```

To:

```
[
    <FilterGroup />
    <Conjunction />  
    <FilterGroup />
    <Conjunction />
    <FilterGroup />
    <Conjunction />
    <FilterGroup />
]
```

My attempts so far have led me to:

```
filterGroups.filter(function(filterGroup, index) {
    if(index !== filterGroups.length-1){
        filterGroups.push(<Conjunction key={index} />);
    }
})
```

I need to replace `push()` as it appends the element onto the end of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual React-like way would be to create a *new* array:

```
const result = [];
for (const entry of original) {
    if (result.length > 0) {
        result.push("<Conjunction />");
    }
    result.push(entry);
}
```

Example using strings instead of elements:

```js
var original = [
    "<FilterGroup />",
    "<FilterGroup />",
    "<FilterGroup />",
    "<FilterGroup />"
];
const result = [];
for (const entry of original) {
    if (result.length > 0) {
        result.push("<Conjunction />");
    }
    result.push(entry);
}
console.log(result);
```

*(Yes, you can shoe-horn that into a `reduce` call, because **any** array operation can be shoe-horned into a `reduce` call, but it doesn't buy you anything.)*

But if you want to *modify* an existing array, you can use `splice`:

```
for (let i = theArray.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
    theArray.splice(i, 0, "<Conjunction />");
}
```

Example using strings instead of elements:

```js
var theArray = [
    "<FilterGroup />",
    "<FilterGroup />",
    "<FilterGroup />",
    "<FilterGroup />"
];
for (let i = theArray.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
    theArray.splice(i, 0, "<Conjunction />");
}
console.log(theArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a reduce operation to include the Conjunction component after the FilterGroup component:

```
filterGroups.reduce(function (acc, element, index, array){
    if(idx < array.length - 1) {
        return acc.concat([element, <Conjunction key={index + 1} />]);
    } else {
        return acc.concat([element])
    }
}, []);
```

But I must admit that this looks a bit weird, maybe you want to do that when you are iterating on the data array when creating the filterGroups array.